# Chrome devtools - Throttle network after page load

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to test my webpages loading steps, but as I'm lazy, I would love to avoid changing the `throttling` settings every time after my  page has been loaded.

Here would be the perfect flow:

1. page loads without throttling
2. after this load, all requests are slowed down with +/- 10s ping

This way, I wouldn't have to change throttling for page reloading during dev but I still have really slow to test my loader steps.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Hello rbansal. It was 3 years ago but I don't remember having found a solution for this :-(